# Auto insert into mysql database every 2sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I have a code of getting latitude and longitude of a user. This is the code I was using to get lat and long:

```
function showlocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);
}

function callback(position) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

I want to insert lat and long of the user every 2sec.

Comment: Try to Use  CRON JOB

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan Good idea, but cronjobs don't support seconds, so you need a combination of PHP timers and cronjobs

Comment: What server side stack are you running? You can't do it using JS alone.

Comment: Cronjob for every 2 second will suck the resources.BTW cron can be set minimum 1 min (excluding tricks)

Comment: If you read this data from client, than you should use some REST API - url, where you will post data from client to server. Backend must check whether location was changed or not (with some proximity), and if it changes - decide whether to update location of user. At frontend 
reasonably to use Interval for periodical action (window.setInterval())

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, you need to play with it to fit your needs:

First: HTML/JavaScript/jQuery

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.setInterval(function() {
        showlocation();
      }
                         , 2000);  // 2000==2 seconds
      function showlocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);
      }
      function callback(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;
        $.post('processor.php', 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon, function(response) {
          //alert(response);
        }
              );;
      }
    </script>
    Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>
    <br/> 
    Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second:

**processor.php**

```
    <?php
    $lat=$_POST["lat"];
    $lon=$_POST["lon"];
    // insert into database
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");
    $sql="INSERT INTO location_tbl (latitude, longitude) VALUES ('$lat','$lon')";  
    // You might need some conditional insert here and for every 2 seconds you will get lots of records in database!

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   // return 'done';
    ?>
```

[This stack-overflow  post could be a good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16380544/6826238)

Note that it need user permission to share location, otherwise it won't work properly.

**The solution provided is for educational purpose only**...

There are many other practical ways to achieve the question's goal.

Why don't you use some PHP IP Geo Location Class/API, and re-log the Longitude, Latitude once changed?

Comment: Thanks Works perfectly... This is what i expectd... So much of thanks